# Trying to solve nested weights issue in linear layout (possibly using relative layout)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a calculator app and wish to have:

1. buttons in multiple rows.
2. buttons should fill up the entire screen size and leave no white space below.

This has been realized successfully using nested linear layouts. However, android lint points out the inefficiency in 'nested weights' in the linear layout. Please suggest a way to resolve it or realize the same using relative layout.

Following is a sample of the linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="clickDigit"
        android:text="@string/button_7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="clickDigit"
        android:text="@string/button_8" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_dot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="clickDot"
        android:text="@string/button_dot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="clickDigit"
        android:text="@string/button_0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the a screenshot achieved using nested linear layouts and I wish to achieve the same using relative layout.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please suggest a way to resolve it or realize the same using relative
>   layout.

Use an anchor view at the middle of the `RelativeLayout` and place two `Buttons` in a weighted `LinearLayout` on each side of that anchor view. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <View android:id="@+id/anchor" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <!-- the C button part -->
    <Linearlayout android:id="@+id/firstRow" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/anchor">
          <View android:layout_weight="1" />
          <Button android:text="C" android:layout_weight="1" />  
    </LinearLayout>  

    <Linearlayout android:id="@+id/firstRowPart2" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/anchor" android:below="@id/firstRow">
         <Button android:text="3" android:layout_weight="1" />  
          <Button android:text="+" android:layout_weight="1" />  
    </LinearLayout>  


    <Linearlayout android:id="@+id/firstRowPart1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/anchor" android:below="@id/firstRow">
         <Button android:text="1" android:layout_weight="1" />  
          <Button android:text="2" android:layout_weight="1" />  
    </LinearLayout>  

    <!-- rest of the rows -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see this would require increasing the layout depth by one plus adding additional views to the layout so in the end the performance increase wouldn't be that big.

A better way to do that layout would be to use a `TableLayout` set to stretch all the columns(in this case you'll need only some additional `TableRows`, 5 to be more precise).

A even better way to do that layout would be to create your own custom layout so you'll be able to place those `Buttons` in a grid like(and should be quite easy to make) using just one layout(and without weights).

> However, android lint points out the inefficiency in 'nested weights'
>   in the linear layout.

It's nice that you take this in consideration(and you should) but in your case the app is probably small/lightweight so those nested weights will not have such a big impact on the app's performance. Just an opinion, don't downvote just for this.

Comment: This helped me achieve the horizontal distribution of the buttons to fill up the width in an equal proportion. The anchor view was a new and exciting concept. Extending it to have a vertically centered view, I could achieve a vertical distribution to realize the layout I wanted.

A mistake in the layout_centerHorizontally param, it should have been layout_centerHorizontal instead.

Also, agreed on the two other suggestions on creating a custom layout and the negligible impact of the nested weights on this lightweight app.

Comment: @vettijack I wrote `layout_centerHorizontally` without looking at the documentation although I always seem to write it wrong. The answer has been corrected.